# SQL Server transform table pivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
Id Type   Value
---------------
100 up    109
100 up    44
101 down  51
101 down  77
102 left  88
103 right 99
103 right 12
```

How can I transform it to look like this?

```
Id   Up   Down   Left   Right
-------------------------------
100  109   N/A    N/A     N/A
100   44   N/A    N/A     N/A
101   N/A   51    N/A     N/A
101   N/A   77    N/A     N/A
102   N/A   N/A    88     N/A
103   N/A   N/A   N/A      99
103   N/A   N/A   N/A      12
```

Comment: conditional aggregation - `select id, coalesce( max(case when type = 'up' then value else null end), 'N/A') as up,... group by id`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is another row `100  up      109` or `100  up      21`?

Answer (score 1):

All you need are some Case statements:

```
select 
  Case When Type = 'Up' Then Value Else 'N/A' END as Up
  ,Case When Type = 'Down' Then Value Else 'N/A' END as Down
```